All Wordpress Website Images Broken
Today my website is showing every image as a broken link.
Checking the Media Library every link is broken, tried uploading new image files today they are also broken.
Checking my hosting File Manager the images are all still there with the same Urls, newly uploaded images are also showing up there.
I've gone through & deleted any strictly unnecessary plugins with no luck & no other recent updates.
I've reached out to my Hosting provider but as of yet no response from them.
Any other ideas I could try, getting desperate!?

You'll have to find out what your hosting provider says.

It sounds like a frustrating issue, but there are a few troubleshooting steps you can take to try to resolve the problem:

Check File Permissions: Ensure that the file permissions for your images in the hosting file manager are set correctly. They should typically be set to 644 for files and 755 for directories. Incorrect permissions could cause the images to appear as broken links.

Clear Cache: If you're using any caching plugins or CDN services, clear the cache to ensure that the latest versions of your images are being served. Cached versions of the images could be outdated or corrupted, leading to broken links.

Check .htaccess File: Sometimes, issues with the .htaccess file can cause problems with image loading. Make sure your .htaccess file is not blocking access to the images and that there are no rules conflicting with the image URLs.

Test with Different Browsers: Check if the issue persists across different web browsers. Sometimes, browser-specific issues can cause images to appear as broken links.

Inspect Console for Errors: Use the browser's developer tools to inspect the console for any error messages related to image loading. This can provide clues about the underlying issue.

Verify Image URLs: Double-check the URLs of the images in your website's HTML code. Ensure that the URLs are correctly pointing to the images in your hosting file manager.

Test on Different Devices: If possible, test your website on different devices (e.g., desktop, mobile) and networks to see if the issue is device or network-specific.

Temporary URL: If your website is using a temporary URL provided by your hosting provider, ensure that the image URLs are configured correctly to reflect the temporary domain.

Contact Hosting Support: While you've already reached out to your hosting provider, follow up with them to expedite the resolution process. They may be able to provide insights or assistance from their end.


If none of these steps resolve the issue, there may be a server-side issue with your hosting provider that requires their intervention. Continue to follow up with them until the issue is resolved or send me your website link, it will help to understand clearly and may be solved.
